# How to resolve 'Cannot resolve class com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView'

Tags: java, android-studio

First added this dependency in gradle

```
implementation ("com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.1.0")
```

Then place the .json file on app/src/main/assets

And this is the activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_fileName="pumpkincat.json"/>
```

I tried "sync project with gradle files" but didn't work and actually got another problem with the line

```
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```